# Probability that $X < Y$ for bivariate normal variable

Tags: probability, bivariate-distributions

For the following probability questions, I'm a bit lost on how to proceed.

Let $X,Y$ be bivariate normal random variables with $\mathbb{E}(X)=10$, $\mathbb{E}(Y)=-7$, $Var(X)=30$, $Var(Y)=100$, and $\rho(X,Y)=-0.2$. Determine:

a) $P(X<\mathbb{E}(Y)-Y)$,

b) $P(X+10Y<0)$.

For a), I have been thinking about integrating the joint distribution to get the unconditional distribution of $X$ but since both R.V.'s are in the inequality this doesn't seem to be the way to go. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $X+Y$ and $X+10 Y$ are normal random variables.  What are their means and variances?

Comment: Ahhh, so i could use the pdf of a simple normal distribution by assuming that the RV W=X+Y ~N(3, 30+100-2*cov(X,Y)) right ?

Comment: @PsycheD It's plus, why would it be minus? Cov(X+Y, X+Y) = Cov(X, X) + Cov(Y, Y) + 2 Cov(X,Y)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the joint distribution.

[image]

The regions are colored according to your problem b).  Just integrate.

Comment: While the statements in this answer are perfectly correct, the method suggested is too complicated in view of the much simpler approach suggested in Robert Israel's answer.

Comment: So as i understand it for a, I should use the joint pdf but setting the bound so that X+Y<-7

I hesitate in setting the right bounds, should i do either:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^0 \int_{-\infty }^{-7} (X+Y)f_{x,y}(x,y) dx dy$$

or

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{-x-7} \int_{-\infty }^{-7} (X+Y)f_{x,y}(x,y) dx dy$$

Thanks a lot, I already have a better understanding

Comment: @PsycheD none of these two integrals are correct. The second one is closer: You understood that you should 1. "integrate wrt y from -inf to y=-x-7". However, in this case, you should do 2. integrate wrt x across the entire real line. To visualise this, sketch the relevant area on the XY plane. Also, you should do 2 after you do 1.